# EBS Snapshots full backups

Tags: aws-ebs

Is it possible to take a full backup (snapshot) of a volume again after the incremental backup?
E.g. Day 1 : Full backup
     Day 2-6 : Incremental backups
     Day 7 : Full backup again.
The reason : Client wants to keep their RTO low as it will take more time to restore from an incremental backup. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible to take a full backup after an incremental backup.

You can back up the data on your Amazon EBS volumes to Amazon S3 by taking point-in-time snapshots. Snapshots are incremental backups, which means that only the blocks on the device that have changed after your most recent snapshot are saved

For Example:

In State 1, the volume has 10 GiB of data. Because Snap A is the first snapshot taken of the volume, the entire 10 GiB of data must be copied.

In State 2, the volume still contains 10 GiB of data, but 4 GiB have changed. Snap B needs to copy and store only the 4 GiB that changed after Snap A was taken. The other 6 GiB of unchanged data, which are already copied and stored in Snap A, are referenced by Snap B rather than (again) copied. This is indicated by the dashed arrow.

In State 3, 2 GiB of data have been added to the volume, for a total of 12 GiB. Snap C needs to copy the 2 GiB that were added after Snap B was taken. As shown by the dashed arrows, Snap C also references 4 GiB of data stored in Snap B, and 6 GiB of data stored in Snap A.

The total storage required for the three snapshots is 16 GiB.

Comment: Thanks. In state 2, what will the snapshot cover if the 4GB is deleted instead of modified? What would be its size?